# Reading JSON event generated by docker private registry

Tags: json, docker, docker-registry

I have docker private registry and the idea is that every time I push an image to this registry, the image is deployed to different machines. The application for deploying the image to different machines is already implemented. 
However I am struggling with receiving the notification generated by docker private registry. The notifications could be seen here: https://docs.docker.com/registry/notifications/

Docker registry expects a URL to be provided when starting its instance. For example using https://requestb.in/ one could visualize every event occurring in the registry. I am interested in similar but am not sure where to start. 
Any help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you configured so far? What errors are you receiving?

Comment: I don't understand the structure that how the events data could be retrieved from docker-registry. Therefore nothing significant is configured so far.

Comment: I have configured it and able to receive the events. However, for a single event I receive multiple messages and also the tag field is missing in the response. Any thoughts?